# Changing Background Image in a CSS Slideshow

Tags: css, vb.net

I found this on a site and it works well for what I require. It's not the complete code, but all I need to know how to change the background image for pic-1, pic-2 etc in the VB code. What I've tried here doesn't work...

```
pic-1.Style.Add("background-image", "file/images/food/burger.jpg")
```

I'm getting  'pic' is not declared.

Front End..

```
<div class="pic-wrapper">
    <figure class="pic-1" runat="server"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-2" runat="server"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-3" runat="server"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-4" runat="server"></figure>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
figure {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  /*animation*/

  animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
}

.pic-1 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: url(images/slider-cocktails.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

VB.Net..

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    pic-1.Style.Add("background-image", "file/images/food/burger.jpg")

End Sub
```

Comment: You can easily change it via CSS. Don't you want to try that?

Comment: Variable names in VB.NET (and most computer languages) cannot have a dash in them, which is why it says "pic" is not defined.

Comment: (Incidentally, you should use something like the [W3C validator service](https://validator.w3.org/) to check that your HTML is correct - e.g. there is a spurious double-quote in `<li><a href="https://onlinecarbooty.com/account/buying.aspx""><i class="icon-legal"></i> Purchases/Watch List</a></li>`.)

Comment: Some good points there, many thanks. Yeah I've set up some different CSS classes instead and that's sorted it fine